# Google Sheets formula help - total the number of X in a specific data range from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a spreadsheet with multiple pages. on page one i have a chart with row values of months and column values of different subjects.

i would like to have a formula that supplies a live update of all instances of X in a specific data range on page one and the data on page two. (ie: total number of times "Apple" is listed in column B for the month of august, date in column A).

of note: data is added to the top of this sheet every day, so the cells need to be dynamic

thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Would you be able to attach a link to the Google Sheet, please?

Comment: I agree with the above request. Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet, layout, data, data types, etc.; and we don't know the end goal you have in your mind. So while your post makes perfect sense to you (who *does* have all the pieces), it's not clear at all for those of us "out here." For your best chance of receiving help, consider sharing a link so that we can see what you see and know what you know.